# Check why it is not transforming rotate 45deg of toggle button

Tags: javascript, html, css

It is getting the class i assigned but why it is not transforming to 45deg rotate. I couldn't figure out as i tried for almost 15 mins.please check and let me know. So i thought to post it here. Let me know if you can crack it.https://codepen.io/TA0011/pen/ExLyLNe check the link and let me know about the concern.

```js
const sidebar = document.querySelector('#mySidebar')

const toggle = document.querySelector('#sidebar-toggle')

toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleSidebar)

function toggleSidebar(e) {
  toggle.classList.toggle('open')
  sidebar.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
*{
  margin:0; 
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
header{
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 40px;
  width:100%;
  background: coral;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 1001;
}
header img{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}
#sidebar-toggle{
  margin: 0;
  cursor: grab;
  background: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position:relative;
}
#sidebar-toggle div{
  width: 20px;
  height:2px;
  top:  8px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin:  5px 0;
  position:  relative;
  transition:  all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transform: translate(50%,-50%);
}
.open.bar4 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-4.5px, 5.5px);
  moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-4.5px, 5.5px);
}

.open .bar5 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.open .bar6 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5.5px, -5.5px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5.5px, -5.5px);
  moz-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5.5px, -5.5px);
}

.sidebar-header img{
  width:30px;
}
.sidebar {
  display:none;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 15.625rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.open.sidebar {
  display: flex;
}
.sidebar-header {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
}

.sidebar-header img {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 41px;
  float: none;
  display: block;
  object-fit: fill;
  height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-header h6 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/userupload/3158902/file/original-7c71bfa677e61dea61bc2acd59158d32.jpg?resize=400x0">
  <div id="sidebar-toggle">
    <div class="bar4"></div>
    <div class="bar5"></div>
    <div class="bar6"></div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="sidebar" id='mySidebar'>
  <div class="sidebar-container">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/0d/cf/b5/0dcfb548989afdf22afff75e2a46a508.jpg">
      <h6>Umann goswami</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
    Welcome human
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ID selector `#` has the highest specificity. That means that the `.open` class will be overwritten by the css of `#sidebar-toggle`.

You can fix this by preceding your CSS selectors with the ID selector.

```css
#sidebar-toggle.open .bar4 {}

#sidebar-toggle.open .bar5 {}

#sidebar-toggle.open .bar6 {}
```

Also you're missing a space between `.open.bar4`

```js
const sidebar = document.querySelector('#mySidebar')

const toggle = document.querySelector('#sidebar-toggle')

toggle.addEventListener('click', toggleSidebar)

function toggleSidebar(e) {
  toggle.classList.toggle('open')
  sidebar.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

```css
*{
  margin:0; 
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
header{
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 40px;
  width:100%;
  background: coral;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  z-index: 1001;
}
header img{
  width:40px;
  height:40px;
}
#sidebar-toggle{
  margin: 0;
  cursor: grab;
  background: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position:relative;
}
#sidebar-toggle div{
  width: 20px;
  height:2px;
  top:  8px;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin:  5px 0;
  position:  relative;
  transition:  all 0.3s ease 0s;
  transform: translate(50%,-50%);
}

#sidebar-toggle.open .bar4 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-4.5px, 5.5px);
  moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-4.5px, 5.5px);
}

#sidebar-toggle.open .bar5 {
  opacity: 0;
}

#sidebar-toggle.open .bar6 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5.5px, -5.5px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5.5px, -5.5px);
  moz-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5.5px, -5.5px);
}

.sidebar-header img{
  width:30px;
}
.sidebar {
  display:none;
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 15.625rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
.open.sidebar {
  display: flex;
}
.sidebar-header {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
}

.sidebar-header img {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 41px;
  float: none;
  display: block;
  object-fit: fill;
  height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-header h6 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/userupload/3158902/file/original-7c71bfa677e61dea61bc2acd59158d32.jpg?resize=400x0">
  <div id="sidebar-toggle">
    <div class="bar4"></div>
    <div class="bar5"></div>
    <div class="bar6"></div>
  </div>
</header>
<div class="sidebar" id='mySidebar'>
  <div class="sidebar-container">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/0d/cf/b5/0dcfb548989afdf22afff75e2a46a508.jpg">
      <h6>Umann goswami</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="main">
    Welcome human
</div>
```

---

### Example positioning with CSS Grid

So here we create a grid where there is a single column with a fixed width of `20px`. The amount of rows are generated dynamically based on the amount of children. Each row has a height `2px`. The space (gap) between each row is `5px`. All rows and columns are then position in the center of the `#sidebar-toggle` element.

```js
const sidebarToggle = document.querySelector('#sidebar-toggle');

setInterval(() => {
  sidebarToggle.classList.toggle('open');
}, 2000);
```

```css
#sidebar-toggle {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 2px;
  grid-template-columns: 20px;
  gap: 5px;
  place-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(0, 136, 169, 1);
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 0;
}

#sidebar-toggle div {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

#sidebar-toggle.open .bar4 {
  transform: translate3d(0, 7px, 0) rotate(-45deg);
}

#sidebar-toggle.open .bar5 {
  opacity: 0;
}

#sidebar-toggle.open .bar6 {
  transform: translate3d(0, -7px, 0) rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar-toggle">
  <div class="bar4"></div>
  <div class="bar5"></div>
  <div class="bar6"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: and why is it moving to another position? because of translate?

Comment: Yes. The `translate(50%, -50%)` will be overwritten by the new `transform` value. You can *stack* multiple transformations to rotate from center again. E.g. `transform: translate(50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg) translate(-4.5px, 5.5px)`. This will more 50% to the right and 50% up, then rotate -45degrees and translate left and down again.

Comment: There are multiple ways to handle this situtation. I prefer to place the bars with CSS Grid or Flexbox in their correct position and use transformations from there. Or maybe even `absolute` positioning if you're more comfortable with that. Either way takes away some headache trying to calculate the correct positions.

Comment: can you rewrite the code bro?

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: @techieafrohead if that helped you out, then feel free to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Yes done it bro. Please assist me more.

Comment: In what way? If you have more questions, then feel free to create a new post.